# Send messages between sockets

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I have 1 server that's built with C++ and c sockets in Unix. The client is using QT and the socket api that comes with it.

The server sends 345 bytes of data to the client.

Sending message from server:

```
void Moderator::testSynch(){
  int type = (int) SYNCRHONIZE_M;
  //Update all connected clients with info about other clients
  for(int i = 0; i<nrOfClients_; i++){
    const TcpSocket &clientSocket = clients_[i].getSocket();
    int clientID = clients_[i].getID();

    int tempType = htonl(type);
    int tempClientID = htonl(clientID);
    int tempNrOfClients = htonl(funNrOfClients);

    clientSocket.writeData((const char*) &tempType, sizeof(tempType));
    clientSocket.writeData((const char*) &tempClientID, sizeof(tempClientID));
    clientSocket.writeData((const char*) &tempNrOfClients, sizeof(tempNrOfClients));

    for(int j = 0; j<nrOfClients; j++){ //Send info about connectecd clients

        int tempLength = (int) clients_[j].getName().length();
        int tempID = clients_[j].getID();
        string tempName = clients_[j].getName();

        tempID = htonl(tempID);
        tempLength = htonl(tempLength);
        clientSocket.writeData((const char*) &tempID, sizeof(tempID));
        clientSocket.writeData((const char*) &tempLength, sizeof(tempLength));
        clientSocket.writeData(tempName.c_str(), (int)tempName.length());

    }
  }
}

bool TcpSocket::writeData(const char* buffer, int length)const{
  size_t bytesLeft = length;
  ssize_t bytesWritten = 0;

  while((bytesWritten = write(socketFD_, buffer, bytesLeft)) > 0){
    bytesLeft -= bytesWritten;
    buffer += bytesWritten;
  }
  return bytesLeft == 0;
}
```

Reading message in client:

```
 void ChatClient::readMessage(Message &message){

 if(socket_->readData((char*) &type, sizeof(type))){
   if(type == SYNCRHONIZE_M){
        int nrOfUsers = 0;

        socket_->readData((char*) &ID_, sizeof(ID_)); //Set the client ID that server gave us
        socket_->readData((char*) &nrOfUsers, sizeof(nrOfUsers));

        ID_ = ntohl(ID_);
        nrOfUsers = ntohl(nrOfUsers);
        qDebug("%s=%d", "nrOfUsers", nrOfUsers);
        message.setMessageType(SYNCRHONIZE_M);
        messageOK = true;
        for(int i = 0; i<nrOfUsers; i++){ //Update client with all connected users to server
            int userID = 0;
            int nameLength = 0;

            socket_->readData((char*) &userID, sizeof(userID));
            socket_->readData((char*) &nameLength, sizeof(nameLength));

            userID = ntohl(userID);
            nameLength = ntohl(nameLength);

            if(nameLength > 0){
                qDebug("%s=%d", "nameLength", nameLength);
                buffer = new char[nameLength];
                socket_->readData(buffer, nameLength);

                message.addUser(ConnectedUser(buffer, nameLength, userID));
                delete [] buffer;
            }
        }
    }
}
}

bool TcpSocket::readData(char* buffer, int length){
    int bytesLeft = length;
    int bytesRead = 0;

    while((bytesRead = qSocket_->read(buffer, bytesLeft)) > 0){
       bytesLeft -= bytesRead;
       buffer += bytesRead;

    }
    return bytesLeft == 0;
}
```

The problem i'm having is sometimes the entire message from server is not available at once.

For example, first 45 bytes is available in the client. The client then tries to read the entire message (345 bytes) which results in weird behavior. Immediately after the client is done reading the next 300 bytes becomes available.

What is the best way to send messages between sockets? Also, how can I determine if the entire message have been received?

Comment: TCP doesn't provide any kind of message boundaries, it's just a byte stream. You need to call `read()` in a loop until you get all the expected data. If you post the implementation of your `readXXX` functions someone may be able to provide more specific advice.

Comment: Looks right to me. What's the "weird behavior"? Assuming the socket is in blocking mode, `readString` should wait for the entire message to be received. If it's in non-blocking mode, you need to check for `EWOULDBLOCK` error when calling `read()`.

Comment: The problem is when I start reading, only a part of the entire message expected is available. For example, this will result in the client calling readInt(), when the next bytes in the socket stream are string characters.

Comment: Accumulate the entire message into a buffer and send it with one send operation. On the receiving end, keep calling receive until you have an entire message and then process it. You're trying to make an application message protocol work without actually implementing the protocol -- that will *never* work. If you have a concept of an application message, you have to write code to send and receive those messages following the rules that define a message according to your protocol.

Comment: "You're trying to make an application message protocol work without actually implementing the protocol" Not sure I understand what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I don't see why your `readString()` function will ever return until it has read `length` bytes, as long as the socket is in blocking mode.

Comment: I agree 100% with @DavidSchwartz.

Comment: @Carlj901: You have some notion of a "message" that exists only in your head. Nothing in your code reflects that. If you have an application protocol that involves a "message" that is sent, then you need to write code to send *a message* and code to receive *a message* based on your protocol's definition of a message. TCP only provides streams of bytes and doesn't glue them together for the application into anything bigger than one byte.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I updated the post. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Carlj901: That's pretty awful code. Why do you keep calling write and read functions on the socket? You're going to force the TCP layer into disastrous segmentation. (When it sees the first write, it will send a packet since it has no idea a second is coming. When it sees the last write, it will not send a packet since it will then expect another write to follow. Yuck.) You have a message based protocol -- send a message, receive a message.

Comment: Would it be better to append everything in a stringstream and then send it as a big string?

Comment: @Carlj901 that is exactly David Schwartz is trying to tell you, you need first define your protocol(I use the unhappy word package in my answer), what is the content of your information, the structure.

Comment: @Carlj901 could you please elaborate on `weird behaviour`... i understand you are writing a batch of bytes on one end and reading the same at the other end in the same order it was written in... whats going wrong with that?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Instead of ~20 write calls I now have 2, which seem to be doing the trick. Post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some notion of a "message" that exists only in your head. Nothing in your code reflects that. If you have an application protocol that involves a "message" that is sent, then you need to write code to send a *message* and code to receive a *message* based on your protocol's definition of a message. TCP only provides streams of bytes and doesn't glue them together for the application into anything bigger than one byte.